# Google Sheets Macro to create Histogram Chart with specific bucket size

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have recorded a macro to create a histogram with a bucket size of 5. Unfortunately, the bucket size keeps defaulting to auto in the chart that's generated by the macro. Any ideas how to fix the code?

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('M1').activate();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asHistogramChart()
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('M1:M1000'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_COLUMNS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(false)
  .setNumHeaders(0)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('curveType', 'none')
  .setOption('bucketSize', 5)
  .setOption('histogram.hideBucketItems', false)
  .setOption('domainAxis.direction', 1)
  .setOption('title', 'Aged Defects Histogram')
  .setOption('annotations.domain.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setOption('textStyle.fontName', 'Arial')
  .setOption('textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.fontName', 'Arial')
  .setOption('legend.textStyle.color', '#191919')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.fontName', 'Arial')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.fontSize', 14)
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.color', '#757575')
  .setOption('titleTextStyle.bold', true)
  .setOption('annotations.total.textStyle.color', '#808080')
  .setXAxisTitle('Days Open')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.fontName', 'Arial')
  .setOption('hAxis.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('hAxis.titleTextStyle.fontName', 'Arial')
  .setOption('hAxis.titleTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.formatOptions.source', 'none')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.formatOptions.scaleFactor', 1)
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.fontName', 'Arial')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.titleTextStyle.fontName', 'Arial')
  .setOption('vAxes.0.titleTextStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setPosition(22, 4, 218, 1)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
};
```

Comment: Define `keeps defaulting`. Does it means that the bucketsize is never been set correctly or it is set to `5` in the beginning, but then changed? Can you provide a sample sheet?

Comment: The bucket size is never applied. I am sanitizing a version that I can share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation for Google Charts Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram).

When it comes to bucket size, it gives you the following sample:

```
  var options = {
    title: 'Country Populations',
    legend: { position: 'none' },
    colors: ['#e7711c'],
    histogram: { bucketSize: 10000000 }
  };
```

So,

### `bucketSize` is a property of the `histogram` option.

To access it correctly, please modify the line

`.setOption('bucketSize', 5)`

to

`.setOption('histogram', { bucketSize: 5 })`

Comment: This worked but only after I also removed the following line of code: `.setOption('histogram.hideBucketItems', false)`